# Why did not have three parameter objc_msgSend() method?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

> I used Xcode7 #import  < objc/message.h>.   I want to use this function. but this function is only empty parameter method . I found this function takes three parameters in the document

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Short answer: never call that function directly.

Comment: That isn't the right header file; you want `objc/objc-runtime.h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use objc_msgSend you have to cast it to the right type.
I post you an example on how I've just use it in one of my projects

```
- (void)loadData:(NSData *)data MIMEType:(NSString *)MIMEType textEncodingName:(NSString *)textEncodingName baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL{
SEL wk_sel = NSSelectorFromString(@"loadData:MIMEType:characterEncodingName:baseURL:");
((void (*)(id, SEL, id, id, id, id))objc_msgSend)(self,wk_sel,data,MIMEType,textEncodingName,baseURL);
}
```

If you prefer a cleaner sintax you can use a function pointer.
If your method is declared as:

```
- (void)doSomething:(id)arg0 withArgument:(float)arg1 err:(NSError **)err{}
```

You have to do something like this:

```
void (*objc_msgSendTyped)(id self, SEL _cmd, id something, float arg1, NSError**error) = (void*)objc_msgSend;
objc_msgSendTyped(self, @selector(doSomething:withArgument:err:), foo, bar, &error);
```